# predict.glm() on blind test data

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glmnet

I'm using regularized logistic regression for a classification problem using the `glmnet` package. In the development process, everything is working fine, but I have a problem when it comes to making predictions on blind test data.

Because I don't know the class label, my data frame for testing has a column less than the one I used for training. This seems to be a problem for `predict.glm()`, because it expects matching dimensions - I can "fix" it by adding a column with some arbitrary labels in the test data, but this seems like a bad idea. I hope this example will illustrate the problem:

```
library(glmnet)
example = data.frame(rnorm(20))
colnames(example) = "A"
example$B = rnorm(20)
example$class = ((example$A + example$B) > 0)*1

testframe = data.frame(rnorm(20))
colnames(testframe) = "A"
testframe$B = rnorm(20)

x = model.matrix(class ~ ., data = example)
y = data.matrix(example$class)

# this is similar to the situation I have with my data
# the class labels are ommited on the blind test set
```

So if I just proceed like this, I get an error:

```
x.test = as.matrix(testframe)
ridge = glmnet(x,y, alpha = 0, family = "binomial", lambda = 0.01789997)
ridge.pred = predict(ridge, newx = x.test, s = 0.01789997, type = "class")
```

> **Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta:** 
>   Cholmod error 'X and/or Y have
>   wrong dimensions' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, line 90

I can "fix" the problem by adding a class column to my test data:

```
testframe$class = 0
x.test = model.matrix(class ~ ., data = testframe)
ridge.pred2 = predict(ridge, newx = x.test, s = 0.01789997, type = "class")
```

So I have a couple of questions about this:
a) Is this workaround with adding a column safe to do? It feels very wrong/dangerous to do this, because I don't know if the predict method will use it (why would it require this column to be there otherwise?
b) What's a better / "the correct" way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Drop the intercept column from `x` and your original code will work.  i.e. do this, `x = model.matrix(class ~ ., data = example)[,-1]` . Will post a full answer later today when I have some time to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

When you create the matrix `x`, drop the `(Intercept)` column (which is always the first column).  Then your `predict` function will work without the workaround.  Specifically, use this line to create x.

```
x = model.matrix(class ~ ., data = example)[,-1]
```

**Explanation**

You are getting an error because `model.matrix` is creating a column for an intercept in the model, which is not on your `x.test` matrix.

```
colnames(x)
# [1] "(Intercept)" "A"           "B"          
colnames(x.test)
# [1] "A" "B"
```

Unless you set `intercept=FALSE`, `glmnet` will add an intercept to the model for you.  Thus, the simplest thing to do is exclude the intercept column from both the `x` and `x.test` matrices.